# Art-Net for Swift

Tags: swift, macos, dmx512

Is there an Art-net Library for swift MacOS? I am trying to send DMX to control lights connected to a ArtNet -> DMX node.

Could someone let me know of a library or another way to control this

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? Any implementations of Art-Net or sACN you can recommend?

Comment: @drdn5 I didnt. I ended up looking into `CoreMIDI` and controlling LightKey using MIDI Commands